# Spring Security allowes access despite of restrictions

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I have standard security context defined, but it allowes access to secure URLs even for anonymous users (f.e. to /itef/dashboard). Why it happpens?

```
<http access-denied-page="/403.jsp"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER, ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/itef/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

        <form-login login-page="/"
                    default-target-url="/itef/dashboard"
                    always-use-default-target="true"
                    authentication-failure-url="/index?loginError"
                    username-parameter="username"
                    password-parameter="password" />

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index?logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
        <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <remember-me/>
    </http>
```

Answer (score 1):

Order is important. From the reference doc:

> You can use multiple `<intercept-url>` elements to define different
>   access requirements for different sets of URLs, but they will be
>   evaluated in the order listed and the first match will be used.

So the `/**` rule should be last.